# Getting custom text wrapped in auto table jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a requirement wherein a table/autotable needs to be generated on a PDF using jsPDF.

I am able to generate table and download the PDF using the below link:
https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

However, the generated table needs to be something similar as per attached screenshot.

[image]

How can I proceed on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it the following way.

> Use of this autoTableEndPosY is deprecated

```
pdf.autoTable({
 //....
});

let y = pdf.autoTableEndPosY();
pdf.text(x, y+10,'This is Text');
//add 10 (or any number of choice) to y for adding space between table and text
```

Please use the following code from now

```
pdf.autoTable({
     //....
});

let y = pdf.autoTable.previous.finalY;
pdf.text(x, y+10,'This is Text');
//add 10 (or any number of choice) to y for adding space between table and text
```